# Wrap part of DOM with a span for highlighting a part of a string located in more nodes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

If I have a string and I want to search that in a part of DOM for wrap it with a div, but the string is splitted in mode div like this:

```
  <div>
    <div> 
      <p>bla bla bla...</p>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <div> 
         <p>my</p> 
      </div>
      <div> 
         <span>name</span>
      </div>
      <div> 
         <b>is</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Duffy</h2>
        <p> bla bla bla...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have the string *"Hello my name is Duffy"* and I need to highlight only that string.
For now I have made a solution that wrap the string insde only one tag like this:

```
 let start_element = <HTMLScriptElement>document.evaluate( xpath-of-parent-node ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;   
if(node){
          var text = node.innerHTML.replace(/Hello my name is Duffy/g, "<span class='note' data-id='asd'>Hello my name is Duffy</span>")
          if (text != node.innerHTML)
              node.innerHTML = text;
        }
```

expected:

```
<span>
<div>
    <div> 
      <p>bla bla bla...</p>
        <h1>hello</h1> --------------------
        <div>                             | 
           <p>my</p>                      |
        </div>                            |
      <div>                                |
         <span>name</span>                |
      </div>                              |
      <div>                               |
         <b>is</b>                        |
      </div>                              |
    </div>                                |
    <div>                                 |
        <h2>Duffy</h2>--------------------
        <p> bla bla bla...</p>            
    </div>                                
  </div>
</span>
```

but only the string iside span highlighted

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I need to wrap the string in the dom with a span but excluding the rest of the content in the parent node

Comment: Could you please explain (show) what the result should be? Add another codeblock with the expected outcome.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I add the expected HTML

Comment: You want to look for a match in the `node.innerText` property instead of `node.innerHTML`

Comment: What you're requesting is not quite possible. You would highlight all the text, including `bla bla bla...`. I would suggest searching for all the words that you want to highlight and wrap the elements containing those words.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier there is a way, if I wrap all the text to extract and modify the style only of  the right text?

Comment: I played with this a little bit and I haven't gotten very far but I don't feel like playing with it any more lol so I'll just share what I did in case it helps you: https://tsplay.dev/KN7QGW

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't possible to wrap your elements with disregard for the structure, but you can check every text node and replace it with an element that wraps the text if a word is present.

```js
// First DIV in the DOM.
const startingElement = document.querySelector('div');

// Words to look for bundled into a regular expression.
const query = new RegExp(
  [
    'hello', 
    'my', 
    'name', 
    'is', 
    'Duffy'
  ].join("|")
);

/**
 * Helper function creating a span that wraps.
 */
const createWrapper = text => {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('span');
  wrapper.classList.add('highlight');
  wrapper.textContent = text;
  return wrapper;
}

/**
 * Recursive loop that goes through all the nodes
 * and checks each text node if a word we are looking
 * for is present in that text node. If so, a wrapper
 * is build and the node is replaced with the wrapped
 * content.
 */
const wrapTextNodes = (node, query) => {
  for (const childNode of node.childNodes) {
    wrapTextNodes(childNode, query);
  }

  // Type 3 is a text node.
  if (node.nodeType !== 3) {
    return;
  }
  
  const text = node.textContent;
  
  if (query.test(text)) {
    const wrapper = createWrapper(text);
    node.parentElement.replaceChild(wrapper, node);
  }
}

// Execute.
wrapTextNodes(startingElement, query);
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>bla bla bla...</p>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <div>
      <p>my</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>name</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <b>is</b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Duffy</h2>
    <p> bla bla bla...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```